# How to show the correlation between counts and rate?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, analytics, correlation

my dataset

```
Name rate  counts
A    10.3  3
B    15.4  9
C    21.9  11
D    9.11  4
E    2.21  5
F    7.7   21
G    18.9  20
H    55.1  41
```

The dataset shows the counts and rate of people with different names.

I want to know the correlation of rate with the counts.

For example, if the counts is high, the rate is high or low.

Which method is right for showing the connection between the two?..

Comment: The question is unclear to me

Comment: Pandas has a [correlation function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html). Have your tried it?

Comment: @YOBEN_S I want to see the rate change according to the number of counts.
For example, if the counts are high, will the rate be higher or lower? In this way, I want to analyze the correlation between the two, but I don't know how to approach

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes,, But it doesn't come intuitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code:

```
# import requires packages
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read the data file
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# calculate correlation matrix
corr = df.corr()

# prepare the plot
sns.heatmap(corr, annot = True, vmin = 0, vmax = 1)

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

which gives me the following correlation matrix:

[image]

as you can see the correlation between `rate` and `count` is quite high: `0.85`. However consider that I only used the data you reported above, just 8 rows, maybe you should use a higher sample for more reliable results.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the Pandas function to compute the correlation:

```
df.rate.corr(df.counts)
```

It supports three methods: 'pearson' (default), 'kendall' and 'spearman'. More details can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html).

Comment: Negative numbers come out, how should I take this?

Comment: Read more about the Pearson coefficient here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient. A negative number indicates a negative linear correlation between your series.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with numpy to get coefficients between two variables.

```
import numpy
a = [10.3, 15.4, 21.9, 9.11, 2.21, 7.7, 18.9, 55.1]
b = [3, 9, 11, 4, 5, 21, 20, 41]
print(numpy.corrcoef(a,b))
```

If the values in anti-diagonal are positive and closer to 1, then they are more correlated.
The result is

```
[[1.         0.84965646] 
 [0.84965646 1.        ]]
```

Coefficient value is about 0.85. It means they are positively highly correlated.